# No unchecked warnings in NetBeans 7.1 Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, unchecked

I use Java EE 6 with Java 7 and Glassfish 3.1.1. When I choose "clean and build" option in menu it works but it doesn't show warnings about unchecked operations. How to enable it?
And additional question: Is there any way to enable all warnings to by shown in editor without clicking "clean and build"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go in Tools > Options > Editor > Hints. Then select "Java" if it's not already the case.  You'll see a long list of warnings.  Expand the Standard Javac Warnings item and you'll see "unchecked" there.  You can click it to activate it, or even better, click on Standard Javac Warnings to activate all of them.

It took about a minute for Netbeans to really apply the changes; I tried rebuilding my project many times and resetting the options before it worked.